# How to find the object which has the lowest property from a list of objects using JavaScript functional programming?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

## The old way of doing it

```
    let min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (let item of food) {
        let current = Problem.manhattan_distance(player, item);
        if (current > min){
            min = current;
            this.goal = item;
        }
    }
```

From the code you can see that after the for cycle has ended in the `this.goal` variable we will have the food item with the lowest Manhattan distance.

Note: `Problem.manhattan_distance(player, item)` returns an integer

I want to achieve the same result using JavaScript functional programming
maybe something along these lines

```
let smallest_mhd: number = food
        .map((item) => Problem.manhattan_distance(player, item))
        .reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b));
```

but this returns just the lowest number, what i want is the OBJECT that has the lowest number.

Comment: please add the object as well.

Comment: Shouldn't `if (current > min)` be `if (current < min)`?

Comment: What's the point of calling `Math.min()` with a single argument?

Comment: I removed the Math.min() that was from something previous

Answer (score 1):

If your method isn't particularly expensive (like simple math), you can simply do something like this:

```js
const calcSomething = o => o.id;
const values = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 } , { id: 3 }];

const result = values.reduce((result, v) => calcSomething(v) < calcSomething(result) ? v : result);

console.log(result);
```

If it is more expensive, then you could do something like this:

```js
const calcSomething = o => o.id;
const values = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 } , { id: 3 }];

const result = values.reduce((result, obj) => {
  const calc = calcSomething(obj);
  return calc < result.calc ? { obj, calc } : result
}, { obj: null, calc: Number.MAX_VALUE });

console.log(result.obj);
```

This avoids having to rerun the calculation. The key is to make sure you initialize it with an object that has the initial calculation set to the maximum value, so it will be overridden by the first loop.

This second approach is like creating an `map` of pairs of calcuation and objects, but without needing the extra loop that comes from a separate map (since you don't need all of them, just the minimum one).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this probably:

```
let smallest_mhd: number = food
        .map((item) => [item, Problem.manhattan_distance(player, item)])
        .reduce((a, b) => a[1] < b[1] ? a : b);
```

the key is not to *loose* the mapping between the **item** and its **distance** value. The object is then the index `0` of the result.

Comment: Do you mean `[item, Problem.manhattan_distance(player, item)]`?

Comment: I need the object. From the looks of it, I'd guess that this returns a two element array, do I need to use map again?

Comment: @AquaSolid no, just take the first element(0-index) of the resulting array.

Comment: `let smallest_mhd: Point = food
            .map((item) => [item, Problem.manhattan_distance(player, item)])
            .reduce((a, b) => a[1] < b[1] ? a : b)[0][1];`
This works, but it's very unreadable

Comment: @AquaSolid I didn't modify it a lot with the idea to keep close to what you had from the start. Is no that unreadable if you structure it well I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the property and return the object. A the the end take the `item` property as result.

```
let smallest_mhd = food
        .map(item => ({ item, value: Problem.manhattan_distance(player, item) }))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.value < b.value ? a : b)
        .item;
```